# ¿Cómo puedo obtener los parámetros mediante un servicio en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, servicio

Estoy creando un servicio en Python mediante la libreria Flask, cree el servicio en localhost:8080 y cuando se quiere consumir el servicio, se van a ingresar parámetros sobre la misma url. Por ejemplo: localhost:8080/consumo

La Lógica basica de la creación del servicio es la siguiente:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello World"
```

Lo que quiero es que mediante las librerías de Python o de Flask, pudiera obtener la palabra "consumo" para usarlo dentro del código de Python y realizar instrucciones con la misma.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda con esto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabo de encontrar en la documentación de flask mediante el siguiente url: https://exploreflask.com/en/latest/views.html efectivamente hay una forma de tomarla como yo queria y es la siguiente:

```
@app.route('/<example>')
def consume(example):
    return example
```

Mediante el uso de '< >' toma lo que esta después del '/' como un parámetro. Hay que tener en cuenta que lo que se va a consumir después del slash no tenga más slash's (P.e. localhost:8080/consumo/ejemplo) debido a que no encontrará la ruta y retornará un 404.

Gracias al ejemplo anterior lo que retorna del consumo, va a ser lo que se ingrese en la url.Por ejemplo: 
Se ingresó a localhost:8080/parametro1
Lo que retorna el servicio va a ser literalmente 'parametro1'. Esto nos facilitará el uso del parametro1 como una variable que posteriormente se podrá usar durante el código.